# use of dropdown list PHP

Tags: php

i have two questions. this is my code (Iranian calender), the problem is when i want see results. all values of year and month and day showns as '$year' and 'month' and 'day'.

[image]

```
 <?php

            echo'<select dir="rtl" name="year">';
            for($year=1388;$year<=1410;$year++)
            { 
            echo '<option value="$year">$year</option>';


            } 
echo'</select>';


echo'<select dir="rtl" name="month">';
for($month=1;$month<=12;$month++)
            {


            echo '<option value="$month">$month</option>';

            }
echo'</select>';


echo'<select dir="rtl" name="day">';
for($day=1;$day<=31;$day++)
            {


            echo '<option value="$day">$day</option>';

            }
echo'</select>';
            ?>
```

**second question:**

and i need another thing. in Iranian calendar month 1 to 6 have 31 days and 7 to 12 have 30 days so i need a conditional expression when user choose month 1 to 6 show 31 days to choose and when user chooses month 7 to 121 show 30 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use double quotes inside of single quotes so it will be rendered as string.
Make the changes accordingly:

From:

```
echo '<option value="$year">$year</option>';
```

To:

```
echo '<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';

echo '<option value="'.$month.'">'.$month.'</option>';

echo '<option value="'.$day.'">'.$day.'</option>';
```

EDIT (answer to your second question):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecrgLpwp/2/)

First you need to give an `id` attribute to your `select` fields.

```
<select dir="rtl" name="month" id="month">

<select dir="rtl" name="day" id="day">
```

Then you need to add some JQuery code that checks if month is greater than 6 so it will remove the last option (only if days are 31). If month is equal of 6 or less then will add a new option (only if days are 30).

```
$('#month').on('change', function() {
    var monthValue = $(this).val();
    var dayOptions = $('#day option').size();
    if (monthValue > 6 && monthValue <=12) {
        if (dayOptions == 31) {
            $("#day option:last").remove();
        }
    } else if (monthValue >= 1 && monthValue <= 6) {
        if (dayOptions == 30) {
            $('#day').append($('<option>', {
                    value: 31,
                    text: 31
                }));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You need JavaScript for this. Bind onChange event on month that will populate the day field accordingly.

Comment: I suppose he uses jQuery. But if not, it's very easy to include it. Time to learn some new staff also.

Comment: You put the jQuery code in a <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag at the bottom of your page. In the <head> of the page you have to include jQuery like this: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `"` or use concatenation with `.` with `'`
so this should be:

```
echo '<option value="$day">$day</option>';
```

this:

```
echo '<option value="' . $day . '">' . $day . '</option>';
```

or this:

```
echo "<option value=\"$day\">$day</option>";
```

Comment: @sajad This answerered your original question. If you have another question, then ask another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and don't change things midstream after answers have been given. I did a rollback to your original question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my original question had two questions i did not changed anything, you can see my question. """"and i need any thing more. in Iranian calender month 1 to 6 have 31 days and 7 to 12 have 30 days so i need a conditional expression when user choose month 1 to 6 show 31 days to choose and w hen user choose month 7 to 121 show 30 days.""""

Comment: @sajad fair enough, however posting "2nd question" should have been phrased differently. Many see posts like this as 2 questions. I'll perform another rollback then. Edit: rollback to revision 2 done with typo fixes.